# How to read "{TIFF}" information inside the metadata of a taken picture

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nested, nsdictionary

I am a newbie in objective-c and I have problems reading information in the UIImagePickerControllerMediaMetaData.

```
-(void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)imagepicker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

//This line is fine.
NSDictionary *metadata = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaMetadata];

//This line fail to operate...
NSArray *tiffData = [metadata objectForKey:Exif];
```

I can get the metadata. However, the info inside metadata is a little bit confusing and below shows what inside metadata.

```
UIImagePickerControllerMediaMetadata =     {
    DPIHeight = 72;
    DPIWidth = 72;
    Orientation = 6;
    "{Exif}" =         {
        ApertureValue = "2.526068811667588";
        BrightnessValue = "-1.739497174308802";
        ColorSpace = 1;
        DateTimeDigitized = "2012:02:21 11:53:44";
        DateTimeOriginal = "2012:02:21 11:53:44";
        ExposureMode = 0;
        ExposureProgram = 2;
        ExposureTime = "0.06666666666666667";
        FNumber = "2.4";
        Flash = 32;
        FocalLenIn35mmFilm = 32;
        FocalLength = "2.03";
        ISOSpeedRatings =             (
            800
        );
        MeteringMode = 5;
        PixelXDimension = 960;
        PixelYDimension = 720;
        SceneType = 1;
        SensingMethod = 2;
        Sharpness = 0;
        ShutterSpeedValue = "3.906905022631062";
        WhiteBalance = 0;
    };
    "{TIFF}" =         {
        DateTime = "2012:02:21 11:53:44";
        Make = Apple;
        Model = "iPad 2";
        Software = "5.0.1";
        XResolution = 72;
        YResolution = 72;
    };
};
```

So how can I read the "{Exif}" and the "{TIFF}"?

Thanks for helping me. I found everywhere and just failed to get an answer...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `{EXIF}`and `{TIFF}` entries are dictionaries contained in the metadata dictionary. You can get a reference to them by using the code:

```
NSDictionary *metadata = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaMetadata];
NSDictionary *exifMetadata = [metadata objectForKey:(id)kCGImagePropertyExifDictionary];
NSDictionary *tiffMetadata = [metadata objectForKey:(id)kCGImagePropertyTiffDictionary];
```

All of the metadata keys are described in the `CGImageProperties Reference` documentation page. The `(id)` cast is necessary because all the keys are `CFStringRef`s, and need to be toll free bridged to `NSString`s.

Comment: Don't forget to #import <ImageIO/ImageIO.h> to get the constants